# Mysql Query return array with Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a MySQL query that I need to change to give results in a different format.

Here's my query so far:

```
@bill_area_char = BillsPayment.joins(:bill).where(payed: false,date: from_date..to_date, active: true).group("bills.car_name").sum(:price)
```

and the result:

```
{"A3"=>20000.0, "A4"=>100.0, "A5"=>700.0, "Alfa"=>8000.0, "AMIO"=>40.0, "Aveo"=>800.0, "Bmw"=>20000.0, "Continental GT"=>33000.0, "i325"=>200.0, "Lobo"=>800.0, "Wrangler"=>60000.0}
```

But, I need:

`[{"January" => {"A3": "200"},{"A4":"300"}....etc},...next 12 months]`

Is it possible to return all of these months in a single MySQL query with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: your group call should be grouping by month, not by the car name, doesn't it?

Comment: If i group by date the result is : {Thu, 30 Nov 2017=>100.0, Sun, 31 Dec 2017=>4200.0, Wed, 31 Jan 2018=>18400.0, Wed, 28 Feb 2018=>18500.0, Sat, 31 Mar 2018=>18400.0, Mon, 30 Apr 2018=>18420.0, Thu, 31 May 2018=>18220.0, Sat, 30 Jun 2018=>6200.0, Tue, 31 Jul 2018=>6200.0, Fri, 31 Aug 2018=>5000.0, Sun, 30 Sep 2018=>5000.0, Wed, 31 Oct 2018=>25000.0}

Comment: i need a array months => car name => total_month in hash from mysql

Comment: Try `.group('MONTH(date)','bills.car_name')`  The months will be 1-12 instead of Jan-Dec, but it will get you closer.

Comment: Or even `GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)`. Just grouping by the month will lead to strange results if the dataset spans more than one year.

Comment: result: {[1, "A3"]=>2000.0, [1, "Alfa"]=>1000.0, [1, "Aveo"]=>100.0, [1, "Continental GT"]=>3000.0, [1, "i325"]=>100.0, [1, "Lobo"]=>200.0, [1, "Wrangler"]=>12000.0, [2, "A3"]=>2000.0, [2, "A5"]=>100.0, [2, "Alfa"]=>1000.0, [2, "Aveo"]=>100.0, [2, "Continental GT"]=>3000.0, [2, "i325"]=>100.0, [2, "Lobo"]=>200.0, [2, "Wrangler"]=>12000.0, [3, "A3"]=>2000.0, [3, "A5"]=>100.0, [3, "Alfa"]=>1000.0, [3, "Aveo"]=>100.0, [3, "Continental GT"]=>3000.0, [3, "Lobo"]=>200.0, [3, "Wrangler"]=>12000.0, [4, "A3"]=>2000.0, [4, "A5"]=>100.0, [4, "Alfa"]=>1000.0}

Comment: need a [{"January" => {"A3": "200"},{"A4":"300"}},{"february" => {"A3": "200"},{"A4":"300"}},{"march" => {"A3": "200"},{"A4":"300"}}...etc]

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed results from DB after you got them (possibly slower, but i guess it will be fast enough):

```
@bill_area_char = BillsPayment.joins(:bill).where(payed: false,date: from_date..to_date, active: true).group('MONTH(date)','bills.car_name').sum(:price)
result = Hash[Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.map {|x|[x,[]]}]
months = Hash[(1..12).zip Date::MONTHNAMES.compact]
@bill_area_char.each { |k, v| result[months[k[0]]] << {k[1]=>v} }
```